# how to scroll a scroll specific div using python selenuim?

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='watch_feed']/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span").click()
time.sleep(3)
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
time.sleep(1)
scr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[3]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scr)
```

[image]

Looking forward for a solution so as to scoll untill the last react in the list .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try scroll to view which will scroll to specific element

```py
element = # Div where you want To scroll
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: i tried it nothing happens ,but the code executes without errors